# Regex to check only numbers(negative and positive)

Tags: javascript, regex

There is an input field on the JSP where users can enter numbers(negative and positive both).
I've a JS function that checks on each key up event on the input field is not a number, it should replace it with blank.

```
var txt = $(elem).val();
if(!(txt.match(/^-?[0-9]*$/))) {    
    $(elem).val(txt.replace(/^-?[0-9]+/g, ''));
  }
```

My if condition is working fine, but I'm not able to create a regex for replacing.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** question was clarified that only numeric values should be accepted

You could just check that the number is `< 0` after removing all non-numeric characters:

```
// remove all non-numeric characters
var txt = $(elem).val().replace(/[^\-0-9]/g, '');
if(parseInt(txt) < 0)){
  // negative number
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry - My bad: I put the question in wrong way - Users can enter numbers only - both negative and positive. I'll edit the question

Comment: Why are you checking only for negative number. I've to not allow the user to enter any other character other than number except for the first character that could be - sign(for a negative number).

Comment: I appreciate your help. The jsfiddle was pretty close, but it breaks for one scenario: ----123---- (user can enter multiple times - sign before and after the number.) :(

Answer (score 1):

To check if a number do this

```
var txt = $(elem).val(); 

if (!isNAN(txt) && parseInt(txt) >=0) {
    //validate
} else {
    // Invalidate
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Suppose if the user enters 1a0, the parseInt(1a0) is 1, which is wrong.